# Output console doesn't work

Tags: swift, console, output

OS Sierra, xcode 8.3.3. Output console nothing shows. How to make it work?
 [See img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4yti.png)

Comment: Menu View > Debug Area > Show Debug Area

Comment: I know how to activate console, but window is clear and console doesn't work, it's look like a bug. 

import UIKit
var str = "Hello, playground"
 
still displays nothing in the output window.